# need idea to display login failure result in same web page

Tags: php, javascript, authentication

A little confused. I have a user login form. As usual user has to enter ID and password and then click on login button. If the login fails then I need to show the login failure message on the same page just below my password text input area. I am using php for server side and javascript for client side coding.

Is it possible to do this with going to another web page.

I am following just as in google login form.

Please share some idea how can i implement it.

Comment: Have you tried something? Show some code to help you

Answer (score 0):

yes absolutely you can do it and most of the RAD happens that way. You would use AJAX to do that. You can use jquery to send an ajax request to your php function. jQuery will make ajax a breeze for you.
if you give us more details or code to work with, we can help you better
thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Make a php script that login user and answer to client with content-type 'application/json'. This script must get username and password and return (for example) the following if authentication is OK:

```
{
    "result": "OK"
}
```

**Important**. The php script must login a user if his username and his password is correct, otherwise mustn't.

2) Your javascript makes AJAX request to the .php script (username, password) and redirect user to the next page if result is "OK". The page must redirect the user backward (to the login page) if the user is not authenticated indeed.

```
function success( data )
{
    if( data[ 'result' ] == "OK" )
    {
        document.location.href='/your-next-url';
    }
    else
    {
       // a message about auth. error
    }
}
```

3) Otherwise (if result is not OK) your php script must return something like:

```
{
    "result": "FAIL"
}
```

If your Javascript client gets the such response it mustn't redirect to the next page, but must show the authentication problem.

So, if user tries to access /your-next-url/ but is not authenticated he will be returned back.